# i18n and Numeric Ranges

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization

I understand how to use `NSNumberFormatter` and `NSLocalizedString` to create a string so that displayed numeric fields use periods and commas correctly for the i18n aspects.

```
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSString *numberString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:@(11.0987)];
rangeStartLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"Start range: %@ ", nil), numberString];
```

But is there any way to do the same for the display of a range between two decimal numbers? Right now, I have decimal ranges pre-calculated as NSStrings (`@"119.3-124.4"`, for example) for display on the screen. If I want to internationalize the string, I'd parse the string to get the two numbers, use NSNumberFormatter for each number and then concatenate the results with a dash in the middle to create an NSString final result that has periods or commas for the decimal separator as needed. Or I would create two labels for the two internationalized decimal strings and put a label with a dash in between.

But it seems like there should be a way to just internationalize the entire string all at once.

Answer (score 0):

Why not i18n the hardcoded string just like any other string in your strings file?

In your `en.strings` file you have:

```
"119.3-124.4" = "119.3-124.4";
```

and in `de.strings` file (for example) you have:

```
"119.3-124.4" = "119,3-124,4";
```

You may even change the `-` to some other appropriate format for the given locale.

Then use use the normal `NSLocalizedString` macro just like for any other i18n text in your app.

Otherwise, if you want to create a range string from two number values in your code, do as you stated. Build two number strings using `NSNumberFormatter`, append them together with a `-` or some other appropriate separator for the locale, and assign that one resulting range string to your label.

Comment: I'd rather not create localized strings for all the pre-calculated decimal ranges I use -- right now, I have three arrays of about twenty strings each. I was asking if there's a simple way to use NSNumberFormatter for my purposes. I think I may go for concatenation.

Comment: That would be the best option. As you stated, split the string, format the two resulting numbers, and create a single new string from the two formatted values and a separator.